Filename validation when drop into libraries
I'm using SharePoint SSE with a classic experience.
I'm trying to validate the filename when the user drops it from their desktop. When there are some unallowed characters in the filename then the file can't be uploaded. I was trying to implement it by javascript that will be referenced in the master page, so it will be implemented in all libraries of those site collections. Is there any hint to override those drop events without using the Event Receiver solution? I'd be glad if there are any comments for some discussion.

I've successfully developed the script to do validate from drop event. So basically, I'm referring to SP13 function and replace the current function in SP SSE.
    function IndexOfIllegalCharInUrlLeafName(str) {
    const illegalChars = ['~', '#', '%', '&', '*', '{', '}', '\\', ':', '<', '>', '?', '/', '+', '|', '"', '=', '^', '[', ']', ',', ';', '!', '$', "'", '(', ')'];
    Strings.STS.L_IllegalFileNameError = "File names can't contain the following characters: ~ # % & * { } \\ : < > ? / + | \" = ^ [ ] , ; ! $ ' ( ) or non-printable ASCII characters and extra spaces";
    let consecutiveSpaces = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        // Check for consecutive spaces
        if (str.charAt(i) === ' ') {
            if (consecutiveSpaces) {
                return i;
            }
            consecutiveSpaces = true;
        } else {
            consecutiveSpaces = false;
        }
        // Check for period at the beginning or end
        if (str.charAt(i) === '.' && (i === 0 || i === str.length - 1)) {
            return i;
        }
        
        // Check for illegal characters
        if (illegalChars.includes(str.charAt(i))) {
            return i;
        }
        
        // Check for non-printable ASCII characters
        const charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (charCode < 32 || (charCode > 126 && charCode < 160)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // No illegal characters found
}

